# Create a file in an existing folder-java

Tags: java

I'm new in Java and i still try to learn but i have a little problem with this task..So, i have to open a dialog box for choose a folder that already exists and i have to create a file inside this folder! i have write the code to choose the folder but now i have to create the file. i found some ways to do it but i only made the file outside from the folder! here is what i write so far:

```
    JFileChooser folderChooser = new JFileChooser();
    folderChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int user = folderChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (user == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File folder = folderChooser.getSelectedFile();

    File f = new File("test.txt");
    f.createNewFile();
```

can someone help me?

Comment: You need to add the path before the filename because it doesn't know the selected path and will create it on the current application path.

Answer (score 1):

```
File f = new File(folder, "test.txt");
f.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the selected path to the file you want to create. If you don't add it will use the current application path, not the one you want.

So try this

```
File file = new File(folder, "test.txt");
... //Whatever you want to do here with it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide selected directory path, else it will create on current application path.

```
JFileChooser folderChooser = new JFileChooser();
folderChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
int user = folderChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
if (user == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
File folder = folderChooser.getSelectedFile();

File f = new File(folder,"test.txt");
f.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following program will create a text file and write words to it. Think this will help someone

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class WriterFile {
    public void writing() {
        try {
            //Whatever the file path is.
            File statText = new File("statsTest.txt");
            FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(statText);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);    
            Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            w.write("Write to file !!!!");
            w.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Something went wrong !!!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        WriterFile write = new WriterFile();
        write.writing();
    }
}
```